# Differentiate between single-click and double-click in R Leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, plugins, shiny, leaflet

I've built out a leaflet map in shiny that, when single-clicked on, zooms out to a set bound. Unfortunately, this seems to have rendered the "double-click-to-zoom" functionality useless. Anytime I try to double-click to zoom in on the map, it zooms out to the set bounds (as it registers the single-click, and not the double-click). I've done quite a bit of reading, and there seems to be a leaflet-plugin work-around to this (link [here](https://github.com/Outdooractive/leaflet-singleclick_0.7)). Unfortunately, even after following [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-leaflet-plugins-in-rstudio/29339) guide, I have not been able to implement the plugin.

I have attached simplified, reproducible code below.

How do I implement the plugin, and is this the most efficient way to differentiate between click-types? If not, what would be?

Thanks!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles %>% setView(lat = 46.73135,lng = 12.32733,12)
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_click,{

    leafletProxy("map") %>% flyToBounds(lng1 =-25.555731 ,lat1 = 69.200741,lng2 = 51.436455,lat2 =35.833665 )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```